# Closest rational approximation of $\sqrt x$ with denominator having prime powers $\lt n$

Tags: prime-numbers, approximation, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

I am representing denominators in rational numbers with powers of their prime factors for easy multiplication and division in lowest terms (by adding and subtracting the prime powers).  I would like to know how to find the best rational approximation of $\sqrt x$ (with $x$ square-free) with a denominator with prime powers less than $n$.
$$
\sqrt x \approx \frac p q
$$
If $n = 10$, the denominator $q$'s prime powers are limited to $2^a\times3^b\times5\times7$ where $a, b \in \mathbb Z \geq 0$ and $a \leq 3, b \leq 2$.  Is there a known method to find the best rational approximation with this limitation?  Continued fraction convergents do not admit a limit on the prime powers of the denominator, at least not how they are usually formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing fractions not in lowest terms, you can assume the denominator is
$q = 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 7$.  Then you just want $p$ to be the closest integer to $q \sqrt{x}$.

EDIT: Note that this is assuming "best" means least $\left| \sqrt{x} - p/q \right|$.  There are other notions of "best approximation", to which this would not apply.

Comment: And a smaller denominator term will never produce a better result (e.g. $2^2$ instead of $2^3$)?

Comment: If it does, you write $p/2^2$ as $2p/2^3$.

Comment: In response to your edit, that is in fact what I meant by "best" and seems to be a common interpretation, which is why I said "closest" in the title (which I know is also somewhat ambiguous).